# How to select count using sub-select in sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get a count of an inner join. Should I use a sub-select?

```
const users = db.queryEntries(
  "SELECT username, created_at, email, phone FROM users WHERE contactme = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC"
);
```

There's another table called `searches` that has a `user_id` attribute. I want to get the number of searches for each user returned in the first query.

Would be something like:

```
SELECT count(*) as total
FROM searches
WHERE searches.user_id = user.id
```

...such that the first query will return `total` for each user

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect resut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you can try to use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY` in subquery, then do `JOIN` by userid

```
SELECT u.username, u.created_at, u.email, u.phone ,s.total
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) as total,user_id
    FROM searches 
    GROUP BY user_id
) s ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.contactme = 1 
ORDER BY u.created_at DESC
```

Comment: small typo in first `u.username`. but it works!

Comment: Thanks to point out typo, Fixed it. I am glad to help

Comment: This works, but if there are no searches the user is not returned in the results, is there anyway to show those users with 0 searches too?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done done with the GROUP BY clause, COUNT and a LEFT JOIN. No need to use a sub-select.

```
SELECT users.username, users.created_at, users.email, users.phone, COUNT(searches.user_id) AS total
FROM users
LEFT JOIN searches on users.id = searches.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.username, users.created_at, users.email, users.phone
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM USERS U INNER JOIN SEARCHES S ON S.USER_ID = U.USER_ID ) d

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).